# Indenting in argparse help python module

Tags: python

Consider the code below

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Intro', add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('--help', action='help', help='My Help')
parser.add_argument('--master', default='abc', help='yadayada ydad', metavar='\b')

args = parser.parse_args()
arg_dict = vars(args)

print(arg_dict)
```

The result it gives

```
./test.py --help
usage: test.py [--help] [--master]

Intro

optional arguments:
  --help      My Help
  --master  yadayada ydad
```

As seen as the output `--help` with its description `My Help` has `2` extra spaces before it. How do I fix this/ or remove this extra space?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `metavar='\b'` in your `--master` definition to `metavar=''`.
That will align the message text.

E.g.:

```
import argparse
...
parser.add_argument('--master', default='abc', help='yadayada ydad', metavar='')
...
```

`$ python test.py --help`:

```
usage: test.py [--help] [--master]

Intro

optional arguments:
  --help     My Help
  --master   yadayada ydad
```